# Issue in creating a Function returning a SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I am currently trying to create a Function in oracle Apex to return SQL Query, and there seems to be some errors in my code. Can someone look over it and see what's wrong.

```
  RETURN
'SELECT 1, LAN_ID label,'||
'   '#'              target,'||
'    NULL          is_current_list_entry,'||
'   'http://orig03.deviantart.net/efa6/f/2015/200/5/6/anon_icon_thinger_by_arofexdracona-d920vda.png'    image,'|| 
'    NULL             image_attribute,'||
'    NULL             image_alt_attribute,'||
'    'left'           attribute1,'||
'    'fa-clock-o'     attribute2,'||
'    DATE_POSTED      attribute3,'||
'    RESPONSE         attribute4'||
'from CHAT_RESPONSE'||
'where LAN_ID IS NOT NULL'||
'order by DATE_POSTED DESC;'||
```

Comment: I think if you look at the formatting, it should tell you the problems. You are not escaping the single quotes.

Comment: I am still new to this, do you know how I can fix it so it still uses the value without a single quote?

Comment: Single quotes are escaped with an extra single quote. Check out the answer provided for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the `'` in the right way and replace the trailing `||` by `;`:

```
RETURN
'SELECT 1, LAN_ID label,'||
'  ''#''              target,'||
'    NULL          is_current_list_entry,'||
'  ''http://orig03.deviantart.net/efa6/f/2015/200/5/6/anon_icon_thinger_by_arofexdracona-d920vda.png''    image,' || 
'    NULL             image_attribute,'||
'    NULL             image_alt_attribute,'||
'  ''left''           attribute1,'||
'  ''fa-clock-o''     attribute2,'||
'    DATE_POSTED      attribute3,'||
'    RESPONSE         attribute4'||
'  from CHAT_RESPONSE'||
' where LAN_ID IS NOT NULL'||
' order by DATE_POSTED DESC;';
```

... and add some spaces  before `from` and `where`.